# Unable to save a trained network: " KeyError: 'predictions_ib-0' "

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to save a trained model using `my_model.save('path/file.h5')`. However, I obtained an error message: `KeyError: 'predictions_ib-0'`

I did some research but could not find a solution. I put my code on Github and the link is down below. The error shows up at `In[39]`

https://github.com/xizhenke/test2/blob/master/demo-Copy1.ipynb

Please give me some suggestions, thank you in advance!

Comment: `my_model.save('path/file.h5')` is just an example. No matter what path and file name I use, I always obtain this error `KeyError: 'predictions_ib-0'`

Answer (score 0):

I did more research and found it seems to be an "on-going" bug of the latest Keras (2.2.0+). So what I ended up doing was down-grading Keras to 2.1.6. And it works like a charm. I hope this could help people who have a similar issue.

Make sure you use pip or conda to down-grade. Or you may run into a package dependency issue.